# What is the equivalent of ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter in the latest Azure Storage SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am currently working on a project that uses the legacy [azure-storage-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) package.

I have been working on migrating the whole application to use the upgraded packages, as recommended by Microsoft. I am following along using the Migration Guides for blobs, queues, and tables individually. I cannot find anywhere in the [data-tables guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/tables/data-tables/MigrationGuide.md) or the examples that mentions how to set up retry options.

Currently we have this code using the old SDK:

```
const azureStorage = require('azure-storage');
const retryOperations = new azureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter();

const tableSvc = azureStorage.createTableService(<connectionString>).withFilter(retryOperations);
```

And the beginning of my new code:

```
const { 
    AzureNamedKeyCredential,
    TableServiceClient,
    TableEntity,
    odata
} = require("@azure/data-tables");

const tableSvc = TableServiceClient.fromConnectionString(<connectionString>);
// .withFilter()
```

How can I apply the same retry options to tableSvc in my new code? I also need to do the same for my queues and blobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2nd parameter for [`TableServiceClient.fromConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/data-tables/tableserviceclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-data-tables-tableserviceclient-fromconnectionstring) is the options and this is where you would specify the retry policy.

Something like:

```
const tableSvc = TableServiceClient.fromConnectionString(<connectionString>, {
  retryOptions: {
    maxRetries: 5,
    maxRetryDelayInMs: 10000,
    retryDelayInMs: 1000
  }
});
```

Links to documentation:

TableServiceClientOptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/data-tables/tableserviceclientoptions?view=azure-node-latest

CommonClientOptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/core-client/commonclientoptions?view=azure-node-latest

PipelineRetryOptions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/core-rest-pipeline/pipelineretryoptions?view=azure-node-latest